# FFMPEG error when saving NDI stream to mp4

Tags: java, video, encoding, ffmpeg, video-processing

I am trying to record a NDI stream to a MP4 file(I want to stream the mp4 to rtmp endpoint after saving file). However I  am getting this error when running this class. https://github.com/WalkerKnapp/devolay/blob/master/examples/src/main/java/com/walker/devolayexamples/recording/RecordingExample.java

Error:

```
Connecting to source: DESKTOP-GQNH46Q (Ari PC output)
[file @ 0x7fb4f2d48540] Setting default whitelist 'file,crypto'
x265 [info]: HEVC encoder version 0.0
x265 [info]: build info [Mac OS X][clang 8.1.0][64 bit] 8bit+10bit+12bit
x265 [info]: using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast LZCNT SSSE3 SSE4.2 AVX FMA3 BMI2 AVX2
x265 [info]: Main profile, Level-3.1 (Main tier)
x265 [info]: Thread pool created using 8 threads
x265 [info]: Slices                              : 1
x265 [info]: frame threads / pool features       : 1 / wpp(12 rows)
x265 [info]: Coding QT: max CU size, min CU size : 64 / 8
x265 [info]: Residual QT: max TU size, max depth : 32 / 1 inter / 1 intra
x265 [info]: ME / range / subpel / merge         : hex / 57 / 2 / 3
x265 [info]: Keyframe min / max / scenecut / bias: 1 / 250 / 40 / 5.00
x265 [info]: Lookahead / bframes / badapt        : 20 / 4 / 2
x265 [info]: b-pyramid / weightp / weightb       : 1 / 1 / 0
x265 [info]: References / ref-limit  cu / depth  : 3 / off / on
x265 [info]: AQ: mode / str / qg-size / cu-tree  : 2 / 1.0 / 32 / 1
x265 [info]: Rate Control / qCompress            : CRF-28.0 / 0.60
x265 [info]: tools: rd=3 psy-rd=2.00 early-skip rskip signhide tmvp b-intra
x265 [info]: tools: strong-intra-smoothing lslices=4 deblock sao
[SWR @ 0x7fb4f8893000] Using fltp internally between filters
[mp4 @ 0x7fb4f3820200] Application provided invalid, non monotonically increasing dts to muxer in stream 0: 135 >= 107
Failed to write video flush packet, skipping: Invalid argument
configurationVersion:                1
general_profile_space:               0
general_tier_flag:                   0
general_profile_idc:                 1
general_profile_compatibility_flags: 0x60000000
general_constraint_indicator_flags:  0x900000000000
general_level_idc:                   93
min_spatial_segmentation_idc:        0
parallelismType:                     0
chromaFormat:                        1
bitDepthLumaMinus8:                  0
bitDepthChromaMinus8:                0
avgFrameRate:                        0
constantFrameRate:                   0
numTemporalLayers:                   1
temporalIdNested:                    1
lengthSizeMinusOne:                  3
numOfArrays:                         4
array_completeness[0]:               0
NAL_unit_type[0]:                    32
numNalus[0]:                         1
nalUnitLength[0][0]:                 24
array_completeness[1]:               0
NAL_unit_type[1]:                    33
numNalus[1]:                         1
nalUnitLength[1][0]:                 41
array_completeness[2]:               0
NAL_unit_type[2]:                    34
numNalus[2]:                         1
nalUnitLength[2][0]:                 7
array_completeness[3]:               0
NAL_unit_type[3]:                    39
numNalus[3]:                         1
nalUnitLength[3][0]:                 2050
[AVIOContext @ 0x7fb4f2d48640] Statistics: 2 seeks, 4 writeouts
x265 [info]: frame I:      1, Avg QP:14.03  kb/s: 16.33   
x265 [info]: frame P:     36, Avg QP:21.67  kb/s: 0.04    
x265 [info]: frame B:     73, Avg QP:24.22  kb/s: 0.03    
x265 [info]: Weighted P-Frames: Y:0.0% UV:0.0%
x265 [info]: consecutive B-frames: 28.9% 13.2% 18.4% 2.6% 36.8% 

encoded 110 frames in 15.13s (7.27 fps), 0.18 kb/s, Avg QP:23.29
[aac @ 0x7fb4f6aa6200] Qavg: 65536.000
```

Comment: What video format is your Network Device Interface transmitting (to be recorded as MP4)? Make sure you get a valid frame as the first thing it sends you (and not just random middle bytes of some currently transmitted frame at your connection time).

Comment: This is not an error.